# Loading images in ionic content from my own created local folder using ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to load all the images i have in my local folder into list which i am using in ionic content. These images show be display when my app is starting

I stored all the images, i click in my local folder and now i want to display all of them in my app when i opening my app.

This is my controller to show images in ionic content

```
.controller('ImagePickerController', function($scope, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaContacts) {

    $scope.collection = {
        selectedImage : ''
    };

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $scope.getImageSaveContact = function() {       
            // Image picker will load images according to these settings
            var options = {
                maximumImagesCount: 10, // Max number of selected images, I'm using only one for this example
                width: 800,
                height: 800,
                quality: 80            // Higher is better
            };

            $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
                // Loop through acquired images
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $scope.collection.selectedImage = results[i];   // We loading only one image so we can use it like this

                    window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.collection.selectedImage, function(base64){  // Encode URI to Base64 needed for contacts plugin
                        $scope.collection.selectedImage = base64;
                          // Save contact
                    });
                }
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));    // In case of error
            });
        };  

    });   

})
```

Comment: Please, explain what's your problem.

Comment: I create ionic camera app in which i am taking the picture and storing them in the app local storage now i want to store them in my local directory folder which is inside internal memory on device . how can i achieve this , after that i want to fetch those images into my app Galary page .